# Is there a way to make a scrollable gridview without putting it inside a div?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview, styles

I know a gridview can be made scrollable by including it inside a div and making the overflow to auto. But I'm using tables to align my page and found out that it's not necessarily a good idea to put a div inside a td, so are there any other way around it?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11636/ScrollingGrid-A-cross-browser-freeze-header-two-wa

Comment: You're using tables for page alignment and you're concerned using a *div* inside a td is a bad idea? :p And who said using a div in a td was a bad idea?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram good one :P

Comment: @Anthony Pegram It's not actually my choice, I'm working on a program done by someone else, and for your question I found many articles saying so

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library. it's crosss browser and work seamlessly. [Scrolling grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11636/ScrollingGrid-A-cross-browser-freeze-header-two-wa)

```
<yourNameSpace:ScrollingGrid runat="server" ID=sg1 
       Width=450 Height=240 CssClass=sgTbl>

    <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID=Grid2 CellPadding=5 CellSpacing=1
      AutoGenerateColumns=True AllowSorting=True 
      AllowPaging=True PageSize=35>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor=red ForeColor=white Font-Bold=True />
        <ItemStyle BackColor=#fefefe />
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor=#eeeeee />
        <PagerStyle BackColor=silver ForeColor=White 
                    Mode=NumericPages />
    </asp:DataGrid>

  </yourNameSpace:ScrollingGrid>
```

this will automatically make your gridview scrollable with fixed header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not seem to work with "Gridview", what could I be possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As `gridview` is reader as `table`.

Try using the `overflow` CSS property. There are also separate properties to define the behavior of just horizontal overflow (`overflow-x`) and vertical overflow (`overflow-y`).

Since you only want the vertical scroll, try this:

```
table {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently `<table>` elements don't respect the `overflow` property. This appears to be because `<table>` elements are not rendered as `display: block` by default (they actually have their own display type). You can force the `overflow` property to work by setting the `<table>` element to be a block type:

```
table {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Note that this will cause the element to have 100% width, so if you don't want it to take up the entire horizontal width of the page, you need to specify an explicit width for the element as well.